# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.postcomics.postscomics')

Tags: react-native

I'm starting on React-Native, (and sorry for my English too).
After several researches, I cannot find the solution of this problem.
And I can't really understand this problem.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import  ListComics from '../components/ListComics';
import { fetchPostscomics } from "../action/comics";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        comics: state.postcomics.postscomics,
        //loading: state.postcomics.loading

    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchPostscomics: () => dispatch(fetchPostscomics()),

    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ListComics);
```

reducer:
``
     import {
        FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_REQUEST,
        FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_SUCCESS,
        FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_FAILURE
    } from '../action/comics';

```
import {
    ADD_POSTCOMICS_REQUEST,
    ADD_POSTCOMICS_SUCCESS,
    ADD_POSTCOMICS_FAILURE,
} from '../action/addComics';

const initialState = {
    comics: []
};

function postcomics(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_REQUEST:
            return { ...state, loading: true };
        case ADD_POSTCOMICS_REQUEST:
            return { ...state, loading: true };
        case FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                comics: action.payload,
                loading: false
            };
        case ADD_POSTCOMICS_SUCCESS:
            return { comics: [...state.postscomics, action.payload]};

        case FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_FAILURE:
            return { ...state, error: action.payload, loading: false };
        case ADD_POSTCOMICS_FAILURE:
            return { ...state, error: action.payload, loading: false };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
const store = combineReducers({postcomics});

export default createStore(store, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

``
`Code FectchPostscomics:

```
export const FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_REQUEST = 'FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_REQUEST';
export const FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_FAILURE = 'FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_FAILURE';

export function fetchPostscomics() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(fetchPostscomicsRequest());
        console.log(process.env.API_URL);
        return fetch('http://192.168.1.23:4000/comics')
            .then(
                response => response.json(),
                error => dispatch(fetchPostscomicsFailure(error))
            )
            .then(postscomics => {
                dispatch(fetchPostscomicsSuccess(postscomics));
            });
    }
}

export function fetchPostscomicsRequest() {
    return {type: FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_REQUEST};
}

export function fetchPostscomicsSuccess(posts) {
    return {type: FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_SUCCESS, payload: { comics: postscomics} };
}

export function fetchPostscomicsFailure(error) {
    return {type: FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_FAILURE, payload: error};
}
```

Comment: Plz include your `postcomics ` reducer ... and `fetchPostscomics ` action

Comment: Here is the code (I hope I did it right)

Answer (score 0):

Youy `action.payload` is an object ... and you need to pass only `comics` to your state ... not the whole object

```
  case FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_SUCCESS:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    ...action.payload,
                    loading: false
                };
```

**OR**

```
  case FETCH_POSTSCOMICS_SUCCESS:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    comics: action.payload.comics,
                    loading: false
                };
```

And regarding accessing your `comics` state:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        comics: state.postcomics.comics // <-- Look at this
    };
};
```

Same thing for other actions like `ADD_POSTCOMICS`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work ... I realized that I had comics which was both related to postcomics and postscomics. So I changed, but still the same error
TypeError: undefine is not an object (evaluating 'state.postcomics.postscomics')

Comment: plz console.log your whole `state` object in `mapStateToProps`

Comment: When I do console.log (state), I get this:

Comment: Object {
  "login": Object {
    "token": "",
    "usercomics": "",
  },
  "register": Object {
    "usercomics": Array [],
  },
}
Object {
  "login": Object {
    "token": "",
    "usercomics": "",
  },
  "register": Object {
    "usercomics": Array [],
  },
}